# Fr.write() seems to be writing over many lines instead of the one I want

Tags: python

I am trying to delete a specific line when the time key I have inside it shows that it is expired. Issue is when it invokes the write code to delete that specific line that is expired it is deleting the line I need plus all the lines above it. Resulting in many users being deleted. What is the issue in my code?

```
        with open('keys.txt', 'r') as fr:
            lines = fr.readlines()
        with open('keys.txt', 'w') as fr:
            for line in lines:
                if line.find(str(id)) == -1:
                    fr.write(line)
                    context.user_data.clear()
                    return ConversationHandler.END
```

My keys.txt looks like this.

```
('1372442', 1659568148811)
('1257406', 1659568153834)
('9910858', 1659568157498)
('1620335', 1659568165471)
('7654803', 1659568170428)
('976647', 1659568175183)
('55145660', 1660695274791)
('5496536', 1660715952400)
('15006383', 1658803605159)
('54928044', 79716354)
```

thanks

So lets say the last ID "54928044" is invalid because the timecode is expired.
Instead of deleting just that line, it is deleting all lines except the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with PTB, so I can't say much about the following snippet (I don't think it's a good idea to return from a for loop, I'd pull that out of the for loop):

```
context.user_data.clear()
return ConversationHandler.END
```

but just to be on the same page. When you do this:

```
with open('keys.txt', 'w') as fr:
        for line in lines:
            if line.find(str(id)) == -1:
                fr.write(line)
```

what you are really doing is checking if the line DOES NOT include the ID substring and then you write that line into the file and then you delete the data. I can't quite pinpoint why the first line is the one that's left in the file right now, but what you can try is the following to narrow in to the ID that you are looking at:

```
with open('keys.txt', 'w') as fr:
        for line in lines:
            if line.find(str(id)) != -1:
                fr.write(line)
```

The '!= -1' means that the ID is within that line and you want to delete it. Try it out and let me know if it fixes your issue.

Comment: wow it was the return statement screwing everything up. I deleted it and it started working again. It was killing me because when I initially wrote this, everything worked fine, I added that return statement later on.

Comment: @Ace Glad that helped! It's not a good practice, a 'break' would be more appropriate. I'm still a bit surprised your code runs as you've intended with the 'string.find(ID) == -1'. Is there something special about the clear() method?

Comment: I actually do have a break at the end I didn't include it. the -1 was to not include the space after it finds the ID I think but probably unnecessary.